# Adobe PDF Embed API returns "PREVIEW_RENDERING_FAILED" error

Tags: pdf, adobe, acrobat, adobe-embed-api

I am using PDF Embed API to embed pdf files, but some pdf files are not loading. Random files not opening. Moreover, I got this error "PREVIEW_RENDERING_FAILED" in the browser console. PDF viewer window loads continuously and shows the below error(as in the screenshot below). How can I resolve this error? Thanks in advance

[File preview error ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCi7D.png)

Comment: Can you share the PDF files in question?

Comment: @joelgeraci please find the pdf URL (https://documentcloud.adobe.com/view-sdk-demo/PDFs/Bodea Brochure.pdf) and I'm trying to embed this PDF url in my vue-app

Comment: I have downloaded the pdf file from url and placed it in my assests folder also..but no luck!

Comment: Ok - Well, we know that file works so please edit your question to include the code you are using.

Comment: I dont know how but from today it is working fine again

Comment: Hey question for you - were you seeing this in Microsoft Edge? I'm seeing this sometimes, only in localhost, and only in Edge. Also, not consistent. :\

Comment: @RaymondCamden i see this in Google chrome while running in my LocalHost